# How to extract the frequencies from spectrogram?

Tags: python, spectrogram

I got some code which takes wav songs from one folder and generates the corresponding spectrograms in another folder. However, I would like to extract the frequencies sampled each song when generating the spectogram, to eventually plot a histogram to represent the various frequency ranges in each song. How would I go about doing this?

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
import glob, os 
import numpy as np
import wave from scipy.io
import wavfile
import time 

results_dir = "/home/undead/Documents/MetricTestFolder/"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/home/undead/ShareWindowsDesktop/SampleWavs"):   #LOADS SONGS FROM DIRECTORY
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".wav"):
            filepath = os.path.join(root, file)
            fs, frames = wavfile.read(filepath)

            channels = [
                np.array(frames[:, 0]),
                np.array(frames[:, 1])
            ]

            fig, (ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=1)
            data, freqs, bins, im = ax2.specgram(channels[0], NFFT=8192, Fs=44100, noverlap=int(8192 * 0.75))

            start = time.time()
            ax2.pcolormesh(bins, freqs, 10. * np.log10(data))
            ax2.axis('tight')
            plt.axis('off')
            plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.0, right=1.0, bottom=0.0, top=1.0)
            plt.xlim([0, 250])
            plt.ylim([0, 15000])
            plt.savefig(results_dir + "%s.png" % os.path.splitext(file)[0], dpi=450)
            plt.close("all")
            endt = time.time()
            print "%f" % (endt - start)

#end
```

Comment: Would it be straightforward to include the `import` statements?

Comment: You want to use a Fourier Transform: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/routines.fft.html

Comment: So is there any variable in this file (idk, maybe channels, freqs?) that I can apply the Fourier Transform to get these values?